# Please rename "moon" tag to "moons"

Tags: support, tags

I noticed the [moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon) tag appear today on a question about single moon.  I wanted to change it to [moons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons) because some worlds have multiple moons (and we have questions about that), but I don't have enough reputation to just do it and I can't propose an edit because "moon" and "moons" can't exist simultaneously.

I went ahead and added the tag to a question I asked about multiple moons even though it looks kind of goofy, but could we please fix this while the question count is low?

Nominal tags on SE are usually plural in my experience, by the way -- moons, planets, plants, cities... compilers, laws, parts of speech, users, tags, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. Renaming a tag needs moderator privs so I guess we need to wait either for a SE employee or for the pro tem mods to be appointed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are only two questions which use [tag:moon]. So it should be sufficient to just retag both of them to [tag:moons] manually; if necessary, [tag:moon] could be made a synonym of it.

Comment: I believe somebody with edit privileges can do it by retagging.  I cannot, because there would be a period of time when both tags exist and the SE engine blocks that situation ("tag" and "tag"+s is a special case, I believe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With my newfound diamondly powers (bwahaha), I am now able to do this.  Because 11 of you agreed with me and nobody objected, I have done so.

Comment: <sarcasm>Abuse of power!</sarcasm>  ;-)

Comment: <sarcasm> @Liath, that's what it's for!</sarcasm>